# How can I zoom on a routes

Tags: mapbox-android

what is the better way for zoom the map to show all the route after getting it?

I tried to do it with my Origin and Destination, but not working well if the route go over or down those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a bounding box for your camera to animate to.

```
LatLngBounds latLngBounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder()
                .include((new LatLng(origin.latitude() , origin.longitude())))
                .include((new LatLng(dest.latitude(), dest.longitude())))
                .build();

map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latLngBounds, 250));
```

Comment: I think you are talking about google maps

Comment: Five years ago, this was the API. It's probably significantly different now, I haven't played with MapBox in a long time.